# A [bold] initiative

Tags: discussion, burninate-request, retag-request, clean-up

According to its [wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bold/info) BOLD is not **bold**. Despite that fact, about 1% are about BOLD for Delphi, 1% are for "BlackBerry Bold", and 98% are **bold**.

Obviously there is an issue here.

There are several courses of action:

1. Change the tag wiki to mean **bold** and create a new `delphi-bold` and retag the ~5 questions that were properly using the tag.
2. Retag the questions that mean **bold**
3. Burninate everything *
4. Do nothing

Personally, I think that we should do #1. The tag was created by one random person 7 years ago and the community does not use it that way.

Should I go ahead and edit it? I could also make `bold-delphi`.

---

## Edit

So the decision seems to be we create `bold-delphi`. It might be good to create some synonyms: `delphi-bold` and `bold-for-delphi`.

Should I make a `blackberry-bold`?

The remaining questions (about **bold**) should be retagged to [typography](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typography) or [typography-emphasis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typography-emphasis)

It might be good to consider blacklisting these tags after they're burninated.

---

* Here's a list of tags that should be burninated if we burninate `bold`:

[bold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bold)
[italic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/italic)
[italics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/italics)
[underline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/underline)

Comment: The text "Do not use for the font style named "bold". " should have been in **bold**.

Comment: Maybe make [tag:bold], [tag:italics] and tags like that be synonyms of a new [tag:typography-emphasis], or of the existing [tag:typography].

Comment: I am against creating synonyms. Tags are to sort things that belong together.  Introducing synonyms will just create diffusion

Comment: @T3H40 I thought that synonyms would just map to the main tag. It's different from creating three unrelated tags that happen to have the same meaning.

Comment: Sure, this is true, but why giving the asker the opportunity to choose two different Tags, when both mean the same? This might be useful if some Software is known by multiple names, or for existing Tags, but as long as we can choose freely,  I am all for keeping it as simple as possible

Comment: Actually, out of the three Tags you Promoter, I like delphi-bold the most. It starts with the general software aspect and finishes with the exact topic

Comment: @T3H40 I've already created `bold-delphi`, but is there a way to change the name of a tag?

Comment: I am afraid that I don't know, sorry, but it's not too bad I think

Answer (score 48):

I personally do not think we should have a **bold** tag. When thinking about whether a tag is good or not, I always ask myself the question:

*Can someone be an expert on this topic?*

I am sure, there are some people fond of calligraphy that are experts on this, but on behalf of programming and StackOverflow, I do not think a **bold** tag really is what we should have. I think, the most reasonable action would be a mixture of your ideas 1 and 2, say

1.5. create a new `delphi-bold` and retag the ~10 questions that were properly using the tag. Then burninate everything left in **bold**

Comment: You mean 1, 2, and 3? We can call it `6.0`. Also I added an edit that there's also an *italic* tag that should also die under this reasoning.

Comment: @Laurel 1, 2, 3 but not 4 can be written as `0111 == 7`.

Comment: I [talked to a moderator](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/41570?m=30010665#30010665) about this and they did suggest creating a bold-delphi tag for the questions that rely on this.

Comment: @Laurel you know what? Let's just do all of this and relax and do nothing afterward. We would then have *one plan to rule them all*. Let's **just** e̲n̲d̲ *this* m̶e̶s̶s̶

Comment: @T3H40 Should I create a `blackberry-bold`? There are q's that are about neither **bold** nor delphi, and are instead about that.

Comment: @Laurel I am no expert,  but I'd say if there is a demand we should fulfill it.